# Show document library sub-folders on quick launch in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am have four different document libraries and each document library has two folders. I want to show my folders under document library in quick launch in SharePoint. I tried to modify from navigation settings but I haven't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The navigation settings (even in Publishing sites) do not allow for dynamic content to be added as such. You would either have to modify the master page (preferably your own copy, not the default one) and include a web part zone under the .ms-quicklaunch CSS. Than you envision using DVWP or XLVT.

Of course, there are alternatives, but more complex, e.g. use Delegate controls,

Answer (score 1):

From the way you describe it the solution does not need to be dynamic? In this case you can simply add your own links in the Navigation settings.

First create a Heading which links to your library then create links which go directly to your folders and position them under the library heading.  If you are not sure how to get these URLs then go to your library and click on the folder then copy the URL from the browser.

Comment: hI dave thanks for the response but what i am looking is when i click on document libray on my quicklaunch than the folders in it should showup in quicklauch it is some thing like arrow mark at document library once i click on arrow the related folders should be shown up.

Comment: You can configure these fly-out type menus but it would take some work with jQuery - there is nothing out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use tree view which is out of the box.  It isn't the quick launch, but you could then hide the quick launch and use tree view in its place.